# birthday from google plus oauth 2 api

Tags: api, oauth, google-plus, google-signin

How to get birthday using google+ OAuth-v2 API.

when, i use the OAuth v1 API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?fields=birthday&access_token=xxxxxxxxx
```

it returns me the birthdate.

```
{
 "birthday": "1991-09-27"
}
```

But with the same scope and using the oauth v2:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/v2/me?fields=birthday&access_token=xxxxxxx
```

it return's the error in respone.

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
  {
   "domain": "global",
   "reason": "invalidParameter",
   "message": "Invalid field selection birthday",
   "locationType": "parameter",
   "location": "fields"
  }
 ],
 "code": 400,
 "message": "Invalid field selection birthday"
 }
}
```

Comment: AM pretty sure that you cannot get birthday from 'userinfo' API. It only provide basic info.